# Change default font GNOME (Fedora 24)

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome

I have a fresh install of Fedora 24 with GNOME on my laptop. How do I change the default Sans Serif font (that websites like this, github etc fall back on)? I want to get rid of Cantarella.

Some research suggest to modify `usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css` but I don't have that file, in that directory there is only a `gnome-classic.css`and a `gnome-classic-high-contrast.css`file there. Should I change the font somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose fonts via [GNOME Tweak Tool](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/GnomeTweakTool).

Comment: I know, but that is just the fonts for window titles etc within GNOME.